# ¿Cómo calcular el tiempo de ejecución de un proceso en Java?

Tags: java

Por alguna razón esto está mal.

```
    public static <E> long calculateETOrdered(int repetitions, int n) {
        long totalSum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            ArrayList<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
            listIntegers = randomArrayList(n);

            OrderedFD orderedCounter = new OrderedFD();
            ArrayList<Integer> resultsIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
            resultsIntegers = orderedCounter.computeFDList(listIntegers);

            totalSum+= (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
        }
    return totalSum/repetitions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes especificar que problema tienes, esta mal pero debido a que?

Comment: Los métodos `System#currentTimeMillis` y `System#nanoTime` sirven para este propósito, pero el uso que les das es el más inocente y lleva a errores de interpretación. Te recomiendo usar un framework de micro benchmarking, tal como explico en mi respuesta en la pregunta duplicada.

Answer (score 4):

1. Debería declarar las variables fuera del for si no en cada iteración del for creará un nuevo objeto
2. Intenta obtener lo que tarda su método ? su for ? o por cada iteración , su código hace lo último , por cada iteración obtiene un tiempo que se va sumando a una variable acumuladora `totalSum`
3. no queda claro el uso de la variable repetitions

   ```
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   for(init , condition, increment ){.... }
   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; // tiempo en que se ejecuta su for
   ```

> si desea obtener el tiempo que tarda su método sería algo así , además para más precisión es mejor usar `nanoTime();` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
calculateETOrdered(12,13); // llamamos al método
long endTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime; // tiempo en que se ejecuta su método
```

Answer (score 3):

El método [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) devuelve la hora actual en **milisegundos**.

Sin embargo, para medir la ejecución de un código (que puede ocurrir en menos de 1 milisegundo), se debe utilizar [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()), que mide con precisión de **nanosegundos**.

```
public static <E> long calculateETOrdered(int repetitions, int n) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    // ...
    // El resto del código

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();

    return (endTime-startTime);

}
```

Si esto mismo se quiere expresar en milisegundos:

```
System.out.println("Duración: " + (endTime-startTime)/1e6 + " ms")
```

Comment: @Elenasys ni idea. A veces pasa (de hecho, es un -2)... El único comentario es el de Luiggi... Bastante para una pregunta que ni siquiera estaba del todo clara (si preguntaba qué funcionaba mal en el código, por qué le daba 0, o cómo medir tiempos y en qué contexto). No me preocupa, a menos que alguien quiera comentar el motivo.

Answer (score -2):

Tienes 2 problemas, el primero es que seguramente necesitas calcular el tiempo que toma el método en ejecutarse y lo estas realizando en el loop, el segundo es que la variable totalSum esta obteniendo un valor incorrecto de el tiempo transcurrido  :

```
totalSum+= (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
```

suponiendo deseas obtener el tiempo en milisegundos se realizaria de esta forma:

```
public static <E> long calculateETOrdered(int repetitions, int n) {
        long totalSum = 0;
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            ArrayList<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
            listIntegers = randomArrayList(n);

            OrderedFD orderedCounter = new OrderedFD();
            ArrayList<Integer> resultsIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
            resultsIntegers = orderedCounter.computeFDList(listIntegers);

           // totalSum+= (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
        }
   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    //imprime tiempo transcurrido en ms
  System.out.println("Duración " + endTime + " milisegundos.")
    return totalSum/repetitions;
    }
}
```